# Why I am no able to install audacity from neither the ppa repositories, nor the the .deb file?

Tags: apt, ppa, repository, audacity

Today I have been trying to install Audacity by various methods, including the PPA repositories, the `.deb` file, and through the terminal using the command

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

and yet I have not been successful. When I tried to install audacity from the repositories it shows this

[image]

and when I tried to install it with the .deb files it just does not install and the icon showing that the program is apparently installing just stays in the Unity bar frozen until I reboot.

Could anyone help me understand what I have to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:-** The following steps of removing a `ppa` can be done in better ways as stated at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed).

You did not add a proper `ppa`. As such you will keep receiving that error when you use `apt`. To view your list of `ppas` and external `repositories` type the following in your terminal:

```
ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

There check for any unusal `ppas` something that you don't remember adding. From your output in your question, there should be a file named something like `should be link here.list` or `link here.list`. Remove these files by typing the command:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/<the file name>
```

Also, the following `ppa` does not have a release candidate for Xenial:

https://launchpad.net/~cdekter/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

So, you might want to remove it from the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Finally, update your list, using the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The errors should be gone by now.

Comment: Yes it work. Thank you @raphael. I think it was a problem because I already had audacity installed before I upgraded to Xenial, but now its fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the PPA is concerned you have a malformed line in your sources.lst. as whatever is generating the 404 errors either isn't a valid repository or is not reachable for some other reason and you should find and remove it. Regardless audacity is available in the universe repository so you can simply enable that in Software & Updates in order to install via `sudo apt-get audacity` Second from the top checkbox as shown below.

[image: universe]

Comment: Also, in the Other Software tab, find and remove the line pertaining to the malformed PPA mentioned in the error message.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Well said. Expanded answer.

Comment: When it says "should be link here" it was written by myself, since I have to have higher reputation in order to post more than two links, but I will if can upload a picture of what I get, I do not if is helpful for you guys.

Comment: Updated Answer.